# Sum in each loop when object might be nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to loop though a set of objects (people) and sum the values of a bunch of objects that `belongs_to :person`, for example to get the cumulative years of different types of experience of a group of people

```
@people.each do |person|

  finance_experience_sum += person.finance_experience.value
  management_experience_sum += person.manangement_experience.value
  clerical_experience_sum += person.clerical_experience.value

end
```

However, sometimes I get this error when a person doesn't have a certain type of experience. What's the easiest way to fix this in my each loop?

> undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass

I understand why I'm getting the error, but not sure what is the easiest way to get past it in this scenario

Comment: @phauwni have replied to your question please check.

Comment: Can you share your models and relations? I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do simply like these without using the each loop

```
finance_experience_sum = People.includes(:finance_experience).sum(:value)
management_experience_sum = People.includes(:manangement_experience).sum(:value)
clerical_experience_sum = People.includes(:clerical_experience).sum(:value)
```

Always used ruby on rails best practices and predefined methods of ruby.

Comment: upvoted for reliable answer but need `@people` in place of `People`

Comment: need change in your profile link(experience section) for https://ajaydhande.github.io/ for `carrier` (need to be career)

Comment: @ray i will do that

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This is the best practice lesson I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow best practices like include nested records using `includes` that will avoid N+1 query problem.

If you want to do it anyway then try following:

```
  finance_experience_sum    += person.try(:finance_experience).try(:value).to_i #or to_f if float value
  management_experience_sum += person.try(:manangement_experience).try(:value).to_i
  clerical_experience_sum   += person.try(:clerical_experience).try(:value).to_i
```

If you are using ruby 2.4 or later then use:

```
  finance_experience_sum    += person&.finance_experience&.value&.to_i
  management_experience_sum += person&.manangement_experience&.value&.to_i
  clerical_experience_sum   += person&.clerical_experience&.value&.to_i
```